# Derivative of $f(x)=\frac{1}{\cosh \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x} \sinh \sqrt{x}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives, power-series

Let
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\cosh \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x} \sinh \sqrt{x}}.
$$

> Prove that
> $$
> (-1)^n f^{(n)}(x) \ge 0
> $$
> for all $n \ge 0$ and $x > 0$.

I tried to expand the denominator into a power series as
$$
\cosh \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x} \sinh \sqrt{x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k \left( \frac{1}{(2 k)!} + \frac{x}{(1 + 2 k)!}\right),
$$
but calculating derivatives of $f$ directly gets quite complicated.

Comment: take $1/f(x) = \cosh\sqrt x + \sqrt x \sinh \sqrt x$, then differentiate both sides and try to get a recurrence relation.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb I tried this but without success. Did you obtain any useful recurrence relation?

Comment: Where does the problem come from?

Comment: I think you could use this theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_on_monotone_functions

Answer (score 0):

If you make the expansion
$$\frac{1}{\cosh \left(\sqrt{x}\right)+\sqrt{x} \sinh \left(\sqrt{x}\right)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n a_n x^n$$ the first coefficients are
$$\left\{1,\frac{3}{2},\frac{49}{24},\frac{1987}{720},\frac{150337}{40320},\frac{1
   8279971}{3628800},\frac{3259985969}{479001600},\frac{160318396423}{17435658240},\cdots \right\}$$ and all coefficients are positive.

So, .... ?

Comment: How do you know that *all* coefficients are positive? Or is that a conjecture? And even if they are: I admit that I don't yet see how that implies $(-1)^n f^{(n)}(x) \ge 0$ for all $n$ **and all $x > 0$.** Am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: @MartinR. Yes, it is a conjecture after computing $1.000,000$ terms. If this is true, the remainig is (at least for me) since there is an hidden function the expansion of which (up to infinity) is what I wrote and the $(-1)^n$ does the job. Thins about $e^{-x}$. Am I (once more !!) totally stupid ? Cheers :-)

Comment: Positivity of the coefficients is not sufficient, as the example $g(x) = \cos(\sqrt x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k b_k x^k$ with $b_k > 0$ shows. – If you are saying that those are the coefficients of some “well known” function then I do not recognize it :)

Comment: Btw, the series expansion cannot be valid for all positive $x$ because $f$ has poles in the complex plane, so that the radius of convergence of its Taylor series is finite.